# Why is a function running before the others?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code I got from [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/peanav/pen/DmZEEp?editors=1010) to generate a calendar:

```
    !function() {
            
              var today = moment().locale('es');
            
              function Calendar(selector, events) {
                this.el = document.querySelector(selector);
                this.events = events;
                this.current = moment().date(1);
                this.draw();
                var current = document.querySelector('.today');
                if(current) {
                  var self = this;
                  window.setTimeout(function() {
                    self.openDay(current);
                  }, 500);
                }
              }
            
              Calendar.prototype.draw = function() {
                //Create Header
                this.drawHeader();
            
                //Draw Month
                this.drawMonth();
            
              }
            
              Calendar.prototype.drawHeader = function() {
                var self = this;
                if(!this.header) {
                  //Create the header elements
                  this.header = createElement('div', 'header');
                  this.header.className = 'header';
            
                  this.title = createElement('h1');
            
                  var right = createElement('div', 'right');
                  right.addEventListener('click', function() { self.nextMonth(); });
            
                  var left = createElement('div', 'left');
                  left.addEventListener('click', function() { self.prevMonth(); });
            
                  //Append the Elements
                  this.header.appendChild(this.title); 
                  this.header.appendChild(right);
                  this.header.appendChild(left);
                  this.el.appendChild(this.header);
                }
            
                this.title.innerHTML = this.current.locale('es').format('MMMM YYYY');
              }
            
              Calendar.prototype.drawMonth = function() {
                var self = this;
                this.events.forEach(function(ev) {
                 ev.date = moment(ev.date);
                });
                
                if(this.month) {
                  this.oldMonth = this.month;
                  this.oldMonth.className = 'month out ' + (self.next ? 'next' : 'prev');
                  this.oldMonth.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
                    self.oldMonth.parentNode.removeChild(self.oldMonth);
                    self.month = createElement('div', 'month');
                    self.backFill();
                    self.currentMonth();
                    self.fowardFill();
                    self.el.appendChild(self.month);
                    window.setTimeout(function() {
                      self.month.className = 'month in ' + (self.next ? 'next' : 'prev');
                    }, 16);
                  });
                } else {
                    this.month = createElement('div', 'month');
                    this.el.appendChild(this.month);
                    this.backFill();
                    this.currentMonth();
                    this.fowardFill();
                    this.month.className = 'month new';
                }
              }
            
              Calendar.prototype.backFill = function() {
                var clone = this.current.clone();
                var dayOfWeek = clone.day();
            
                if(!dayOfWeek) { return; }
            
                clone.subtract('days', dayOfWeek+1);
            
                for(var i = dayOfWeek; i > 0 ; i--) {
                  this.drawDay(clone.add('days', 1));
                }
              }
            
              Calendar.prototype.fowardFill = function() {
                var clone = this.current.clone().add('months', 1).subtract('days', 1);
                var dayOfWeek = clone.day();
            
                if(dayOfWeek === 6) { return; }
            
                for(var i = dayOfWeek; i < 6 ; i++) {
                  this.drawDay(clone.add('days', 1));
                }
              }
            
              Calendar.prototype.currentMonth = function() {
                var clone = this.current.clone();
            
                while(clone.month() === this.current.month()) {
                  this.drawDay(clone);
                  clone.add('days', 1);
                }
              }
            
              Calendar.prototype.getWeek = function(day) {
                if(!this.week || day.day() === 0) {
                  this.week = createElement('div', 'week');
                  this.month.appendChild(this.week);
                }
              }
            
              Calendar.prototype.drawDay = function(day) {
                var self = this;
                this.getWeek(day);
            
                //Outer Day
                var outer = createElement('div', this.getDayClass(day));
                outer.addEventListener('click', function() {
                  self.openDay(this);
                });
            
                //Day Name
                var name = createElement('div', 'day-name', day.locale('es').format('ddd'));
            
                //Day Number
                var number = createElement('div', 'day-number', day.format('DD'));
            
            
                //Events
                var events = createElement('div', 'day-events');
                this.drawEvents(day, events);
                    
                outer.appendChild(name);
                outer.appendChild(number);
                outer.appendChild(events);
                this.week.appendChild(outer);
              }
            
              Calendar.prototype.drawEvents = function(day, element) {
                if(day.month() === this.current.month()) {
                  var todaysEvents = this.events.reduce(function(memo, ev) {
                    if(ev.date.isSame(day, 'day')) {
                      memo.push(ev);
                    }
                    return memo;
                  }, []);
            
                  todaysEvents.forEach(function(ev) {
                    var evSpan = createElement('span', ev.color);
                    element.appendChild(evSpan);
                  });
                }
              }
            
              Calendar.prototype.getDayClass = function(day) {
                classes = ['day'];
                if(day.month() !== this.current.month()) {
                  classes.push('other');
                } else if (today.isSame(day, 'day')) {
                  classes.push('today');
                }
                return classes.join(' ');
              }
            
              Calendar.prototype.openDay = function(el) {
                var details, arrow;
                var dayNumber = +el.querySelectorAll('.day-number')[0].innerText || +el.querySelectorAll('.day-number')[0].textContent;
                var day = this.current.clone().date(dayNumber);
            
                var currentOpened = document.querySelector('.details');
            
                //Check to see if there is an open detais box on the current row
                if(currentOpened && currentOpened.parentNode === el.parentNode) {
                  details = currentOpened;
                  arrow = document.querySelector('.arrow');
                } else {
                  //Close the open events on differnt week row
                  //currentOpened && currentOpened.parentNode.removeChild(currentOpened);
                  if(currentOpened) {
                    currentOpened.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
                      currentOpened.parentNode.removeChild(currentOpened);
                    });
                    currentOpened.addEventListener('oanimationend', function() {
                      currentOpened.parentNode.removeChild(currentOpened);
                    });
                    currentOpened.addEventListener('msAnimationEnd', function() {
                      currentOpened.parentNode.removeChild(currentOpened);
                    });
                    currentOpened.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
                      currentOpened.parentNode.removeChild(currentOpened);
                    });
                    currentOpened.className = 'details out';
                  }
            
                  //Create the Details Container
                  details = createElement('div', 'details in');
            
                  //Create the arrow
                  var arrow = createElement('div', 'arrow');
            
                  //Create the event wrapper
            
                  details.appendChild(arrow);
                  el.parentNode.appendChild(details);
                }
            
                var todaysEvents = this.events.reduce(function(memo, ev) {
                  if(ev.date.isSame(day, 'day')) {
                    memo.push(ev);
                  }
                  return memo;
                }, []);
            
                this.renderEvents(todaysEvents, details);
            
                arrow.style.left = el.offsetLeft - el.parentNode.offsetLeft + 27 + 'px';
              }
            
              Calendar.prototype.renderEvents = function(events, ele) {
                //Remove any events in the current details element
                var currentWrapper = ele.querySelector('.events');
                var wrapper = createElement('div', 'events in' + (currentWrapper ? ' new' : ''));
            
                events.forEach(function(ev) {
                  var div = createElement('div', 'event');
                  var square = createElement('div', 'event-category ' + ev.color);
                  var span = createElement('span', '', ev.eventName);
                  div.appendChild(square);
                  div.appendChild(span);
                  wrapper.appendChild(div);
                });
            
                if(!events.length) {
                  var div = createElement('div', 'event empty');
                  var span = createElement('span', '', 'No Events');
            
                  div.appendChild(span);
                  wrapper.appendChild(div);
                }
            
                if(currentWrapper) {
                  currentWrapper.className = 'events out';
                  currentWrapper.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function() {
                    currentWrapper.parentNode.removeChild(currentWrapper);
                    ele.appendChild(wrapper);
                  });
                  currentWrapper.addEventListener('oanimationend', function() {
                    currentWrapper.parentNode.removeChild(currentWrapper);
                    ele.appendChild(wrapper);
                  });
                  currentWrapper.addEventListener('msAnimationEnd', function() {
                    currentWrapper.parentNode.removeChild(currentWrapper);
                    ele.appendChild(wrapper);
                  });
                  currentWrapper.addEventListener('animationend', function() {
                    currentWrapper.parentNode.removeChild(currentWrapper);
                    ele.appendChild(wrapper);
                  });
                } else {
                  ele.appendChild(wrapper);
                }
              }
            
                        
              Calendar.prototype.nextMonth = function() {
                this.current.add('months', 1);
                this.next = true;
                this.draw();
              }
            
              Calendar.prototype.prevMonth = function() {
                this.current.subtract('months', 1);
                this.next = false;
                this.draw();
              }
            
              window.Calendar = Calendar;
            
              function createElement(tagName, className, innerText) {
                var ele = document.createElement(tagName);
                if(className) {
                  ele.className = className;
                }
                if(innerText) {
                  ele.innderText = ele.textContent = innerText;
                }
                return ele;
              }
            }();
            
            !function() {
                var data = [
                    {}
                ];
                data.push({ eventName: 'test', calendar: 'Other', color: 'green', date:moment('2022-12-11T10:20:25')});

                    var partialsDates
                        
                    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.onload = () => {
                      partialDates = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                          data.push({ eventName: 'Inicio de primer parcial', calendar: 'Other', color: 'green', date:moment(partialDates[0].startFirstPartial)});
                              data.push({ eventName: 'Inicio de segundo parcial', calendar: 'Other', color: 'green', date:moment(partialDates[0].startSecondPartial)});
                              data.push({ eventName: 'Inicio de tercer parcial', calendar: 'Other', color: 'green', date:moment(partialDates[0].startThirdPartial)});
                          console.log("a")
                    }
                    xhr.open("GET", "/api/timeAssignment/");
                    xhr.responseType = "text";
                    xhr.send();
                    

                             

            
        
            
              var calendar = new Calendar('#calendar', data);
            
            }();
```

I'm trying to push the information I grab with Ajax into the array `data` the events that I want the user to see, while it does add them to the array and successfully in the calendar, the function that draws a square doesn't seems to add the new elements in the array. This seems to be because the next function is called before:

```
        todaysEvents.forEach(function(ev) {
        var evSpan = createElement('span', ev.color);
        element.appendChild(evSpan);
      });
```

I don't really understand why that function is called before others like `Calendar.prototype.renderEvents = function(events, ele) {}`. Is there a way I can call it after adding elements to the array like the others? Is my approach incorrect?

Comment: Because you run this in a timeout and other functions without a timeout

Comment: @Konrad removing the timeouts didn't have effect in it showing the square

Comment: I think you need to move the `new Calendar()` statement inside the `onload` handler

Comment: @YK1 that's the simplest and (I think) best solution. Thanks!